# IntelliJ IDEA terminal exiting process command (control + c) doesn't work

Tags: intellij-idea, terminal, osx-elcapitan

When working with the built in terminal in IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2.3 on OSX El Capitan the process exiting command (control-c) doesn't work. It only writes `c` in the console and nothing happens.

Comment: what about this? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/running-command-line-tool-commands.html ?

Comment: "During the command execution, click the Stop toolbar button stop."

Comment: No that's not what I need here. Im not running a programm. I want to exit a terminal command.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue.  To clarify, it's when you're using the embedded terminal, attempting to send a kill signal to a running process (ctrl+c) will only print a c.  I only noticed this after upgrading to 2016.2.3.  I'm also runing El Capitan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved automatically with installing a newer version of IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: I also see this problem resolved by update to version Ultimate 2016.2.4

Comment: I'm running Ultimate 2017.1.1 and still have the problem

Comment: @VladShevchenko did you have karabiner running? There could be remapping from ctrl+c to cmd+c

Comment: @RomanT I use Windows and have no idea what karabiner is. Though I haven't observed the issue with ctrl+c for a while, probably because I've updated Idea a couple times now.

Comment: @VladShevchenko ok. I'm experiencing the issue on mac.

Answer (score 2):

According to your settings it should be <kbd>Meta</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>. Normally it is the same key combination used to '**copy**' purpose.

Anyway you can check and use as follows,

- Go to **Settings -> Keymap**

[image]

- On the top-right corner type '**copy**' and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
- The first key pair (here <kbd>Meta</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> ) should be the one you needed.

You can also change the keymap you are using from the 'keymap' drop down menu appearing here, and switch to a different one, if you are not comfortable with your settings. 'Mac OS X 10.5 + would be a good one for you.

Comment: I use Keymap Mac OS X 10.5. When looking for copy I found: command-C.

Comment: Both, control-c and command-c just write a c in my IDEA terminal.

Comment: Same issue with other Keymap.

Comment: very strange then.. at least windows keymap is supposed to work..  ://

Comment: I have the same trouble. Seems like some control characters are intercepted (at least ^C and ^D), but not all - at least ^I (tab) ^J (linefeed) and ^M (carriage return) ARE passed through to the terminal. FWIW - Intellij IDEA 2016.2.3.  Also, FWIW, I used [cat -tev] to determine which controls are passed through and which had their "control-ness" stripped.

Answer (score 2):

You can close the terminal session by clicking the red X on the left of the the terminal tool window, and this should also kill any processes created by the terminal. If you want to run another command, just open the terminal back up.

Answer (score 2):

Control+C and then ENTER works in 2018.3 (in Windows).

Answer (score 2):

Keymapping works if one got a few dime of time in their hands. For me, just pressing "q" and hitting enter comes out of existing command in the terminal.

Note: you wont see anything that you may type, so just go with the flow!!!

Answer (score 1):

For me it was ctrl shift w. But it closes terminal window.
Just right click to see context menu, you'll see.

Answer (score 0):

For me is ctrl+F2 to terminate the process.